# ¿Cual es el error de esta codigo?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$consulta          = "SELECT codigoProducto,descripcion,pCompra FROM productos WHERE pCompra<10.0;";
$hacerConsulta     = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$numeroDeRegistros = mysqli_fetch_array($hacerConsulta);

for ($contador = 0; $contador < $numeroDeRegistros; $contador++) {
    $codigo      = mysqli_result($hacerConsulta, $contador, "codigoProducto");  //*el error me tira en está linea //*
    $descripcion = mysqli_result($hacerConsulta, $contador, "decripcion");
    $pCompra     = mysqli_result($hacerConsulta, $contador, "pCompra");
}
```

Me muestra el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\clase\matrizDeDatos.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\clase\matrizDeDatos.php on line 22

Comment: Que error te lanza?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\clase\matrizDeDatos.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\clase\matrizDeDatos.php on line 22

Comment: `mysqli_result` es una clase, no una función. [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: entonces como podría hacerlo (soy novato, es mi primera consulta)

Answer (score 0):

Ya puestos a toquetear el código para que funcione, podríamos hacer uso de la orientación a objetos que ya permite `mysqli`:

```
<?php

$conexion=new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');

$consulta = "
    SELECT codigoProducto,descripcion,pCompra
      FROM productos
      WHERE pCompra<10.0;
";
$rs = $conexion->query($consulta);
while($result=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
    $codigo      = $result["codigoProducto"];
    $descripcion = $result["descripcion"];
    $pCompra     = $result["pCompra"];
}
```